# Google Charts ColumnChart hard min axis value overflows label (Chrome only)

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, charts, google-visualization

I am building a stacked ColumnChart from the Google Charts API, and all is well - mostly. It is stock information with a double y-axis.

**Only in chrome**, when I set the viewWindow min value to something greater than 0 to adjust the chart, the columns do not stop at the bottom vertical boundary of the chart and instead bleed into the labels.

The chart is here:
http://ir.stockpr.com/mainstcapital/stock-information

Chrome:
[image]

The chart data is all correct.

Code:

```
function drawVisualization() {

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    <?= $chart_data ?>
  ]);

  var options = {
      legend: { position: 'top', textStyle: {color: '#333', fontSize: 10, fontName: 'Arial', bold: false, italic: false} },
      isStacked: true,
      title : 'Historical Dividend, Distributable Net Investment Income (“DNII”), And Net Asset Value (“NAV”) Per Share Growth',
      vAxes: {
        0: {title: "DNII and Dividends Per Share", viewWindowMode: 'explicit', viewWindow: { min: 0.2, max: 1 } }, 
        1: {title: "NAV Per Share", viewWindowMode: 'explicit', viewWindow: { min: 8, max: 24 } }
     },

    hAxis: {title: "As of <?= $last_day_of_last_complete_quarter ?>, <?= $last_complete_year ?>"},

    series: {
        0: {type: "bars", color: '#6d6d66', targetAxisIndex: 0},
        1: {type: "bars", color: '#d4d4d4', targetAxisIndex: 0},

        2: {type: "line", color: 'green', lineWidth: 3, targetAxisIndex: 1},
        3: {type: "line", color: 'red', lineWidth: 3, targetAxisIndex: 0},
    }   

  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Is there some CSS I could do to fix this? I couldn't figure anything out. Or am I missing something in the API? Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The clip-path of the svg generated by google.visualization is not applied due to the incorrect url. This is caused by base tag in head section:

```
<base href="http://mainstcapital.sites.equisolve.com">
```

2 possible solutions:

1.
Remove base tag

2.
Add following function found here: https://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/detail?id=598

But it's unlikely to work forever :)

```
function fixGoogleCharts(){

$( 'svg', "#chart_div" ).each( function() {
    $( this ).find( "g" ).each( function() {
        if ($( this ).attr( 'clip-path' )){
            if ( $( this ).attr( 'clip-path' ).indexOf( 'url(#') == -1) return;
            $( this ).attr( 'clip-path', 'url(' + document.location + $( this ).attr( 'clip-path' ).substring( 4 ) )
        }
    });
    $( this ).find( "rect" ).each( function() {
        if($( this ).attr( 'fill' )){
            if ( $( this ).attr( 'fill' ).indexOf( 'url(#') == -1) return;
            $( this ).attr( 'fill', 'url(' + document.location + $( this ).attr( 'fill' ).substring( 4 ) )
        }
    });
}); }
```

and bellow your

```
chart.draw(data, options);
```

add

```
google.visualization.events.addListener( chart, 'ready', fixGoogleCharts() );
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I'd prefer to remove the base tag, but with our current setup we can't. The second option, although it may be temporary, works like a charm. Thank you so much!